# C# backend Azure

Tags: c#, axure

I have a C# application that is built using the .NET Core Web API template. This works great locally and I can access the rest endpoints in my application.

For example `/api/person/0` where `0` is the `id` of a person.

The problem is with Azure. When I create an app service and use a github repository the app gets deployed. In the logs I see the following partial error:

> Physical Path   C:\home\site\wwwroot\api\gerecht\1

Azure thinks that my C# app is a simple website and tries to access the path as a physical file and not as an endpoint in my application. Why is Azure not accessing the endpoint?

Thanks

Comment: To say that you see that in the logs doesn't give us much to go on. What is the full error? What behavior do you observe from whatever client you are using?

Comment: When I access the rest endpoint in my browser I get a 500 error. In the logs I see this:
```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr class="alt"><th>Requested URL</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;https://myproject:80/api/person/1</td></tr><tr><th>Physical Path</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;C:\home\site\wwwroot\api\person\1</td></tr><tr class="alt"><th>Logon Method</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr><tr><th>Logon User</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you deploy the application to Azure?

[Brute Force]
You may want to use GitHub Action from inside Visual Studio for this.

- Right Click Publish
- Azure (Select appropriate OS)
- Deploy using GitHub Action

I experience this in the past and that was how I solved it.

Alternatively, you could use the Azure CLI from inside the directory that contains your `.csproj` file.

Official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest).